# How do i get an nuclear alert kinda icon in HTML

Tags: html

How do you get this icon ☢ to display correctly in older browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a [Unicode Miscellaneous Character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols). All Unicode characters you can view with `&#CODE;` - the code is the dezimal Code/Number of the character, that you want view. That atomic active sign icon has the dezimal code/number 9762.
`&#9762;` is viewed as followed: ☢

Answer (score 0):

This is called a radio active sign.

For the valid HTML entity use this:

```
&#9762;
```